# Best way to keep textarea synced with server text file

Tags: jquery, ajax, textarea

Hi I'm making a simple application where users can type information into a text area and not have to worry about saving it or losing it. I'm using jquery/javascript to detect changes to text area, then using ajax to send the value to php for writing to server. I have some a basic "busy" lock to prevent overlapping ajax. However, I'm finding that it is slightly unreliable. Is there a better way to do this?

```
var busy = false;

function save () {
if(busy === false) {
    busy = true;
    var content = $('#text').val();
    var file = 'store.txt';
    $.get("storecontent.php", { content_fromjq: content, file_fromjq: file})
    .done(function(data) {

    busy = false;
    });
}
}

$('#text').bind('input propertychange', function() {
save();
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_GET['content_fromjq'])) {

$content = $_GET['content_fromjq'];
$file = $_GET['file_fromjq'];


$html = new DOMDocument();  
$html->loadHTMLFile($file);     
$html->getElementById('content')->nodeValue = $content;
$html->saveHTMLFile($file);

}
```

Comment: Biggest issue i see is if two users are editing the file at the same time, it will be out of sync and they'll keep overwriting each other's work unless you're updating the textarea frequently from the server.

Comment: Your first best bet would be to "monitor" the change on a timer of like every 30 seconds. Not try to update every time there is a change. secondly, you dont need to asign funcs like that in jQuery, you can, but no need, you can rewrite that line as `$('#text').bind('input propertychange', save);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what i would do : http://jsfiddle.net/z4rjQ/

Save a listener for when the text change that call this function :

```
function checkSave(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(save, 5000);
}
```

This function clear the timer and set an other one.

In other word, there is no save until the user didnt press a key for 5 sec (adjustable).

That will allow you to not send thousand of ajax save but send one after he finished typing something.